# pycharmで自動コード補完されないことがある

Tags: python, pycharm

このコードの一番下のcellsは本来であれば `.c` までタイピングすると `.cell(row=, column=)...` と出てくるはずなのですがコード補完されません。
これは今回以外もたまに起こることがあります。
どのようにしたら直るでしょうか。

#### 試したこと

コード補完はされないものの、自分でタイプするとModulesは使用可能
openpyxlの自動補完はすべて補完されない状態でinstallしなおしても状態は変わりませんでした。

```
import openpyxl
def get_workbook(workbook_name):
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\406429\Documents\GitHub\Pythontest\" + workbook_name, data_only=True)
        print(f"{workbook_name}を読み込みました。")
        return workbook
mailaddress_list = workbooks[2]
mailaddress_list_sheet = mailaddress_list["Sheet1"]
phonenum_list_sheet = phonenum_list["回線番号情報"]

cells = mailaddress_list_sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value
```

Comment: このドキュメント [openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) だと worksheet の `c` で始まる属性は全部で3つあるようですが、`.ce`まで入力すれば唯一になるので出てくるのでは？

Comment: ceまで入力しても変わりませんでした。
というより、候補にcellすら出てきません

Comment: その辺の試した状況や、同じソースコードを編集中の他の場合のコード補完はどうなっているか等の情報も質問に追記されると、PyCharmを使っている人からの助言や回答が出やすくなると思われます。

Answer (score 0):

Libraryのバージョンを下げたら自動補完がされるようになりました。

Comment: 質問時の問題の発生する版数と解決した版数の情報があればもっと良いでしょう。